# Get an processing instruction value

Tags: sql-server, xml

How can I get a value of a processing instruction tag in SQL Server?

```
declare @x XML = 
'<root>
  <entity>
    <?ent LOOKUPS?>
  </entity>
  <entity>
    <?ent STAFF?>
  </entity>
  <entity>
    <?ent SIR?>
  </entity>
</root>';

SELECT x.xml.value('processing-instruction(ent)[1]','varchar(30)')
FROM @x.nodes('/root/entity') x(xml);
```

The select statement returns an error:
Msg 2225, Level 16, State 1, Line 29
XQuery [value()]: A string literal was expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need double-quotes around "ent":

```
SELECT x.xml.value('data(processing-instruction("ent")[1])','varchar(30)')
FROM @x.nodes('/root/entity') x(xml);
```